# Scraping the vectorlayer/shp/SVG/GeoJSON from this webmap?

Tags: geojson, web-mapping

I try to download the data from this webmap for further analysis. I tried to look at the network tab, but didn't find any such data. I looked into the JavaScript files, and didn't find any either. Yet, I found some array data calling such as "LAYERS" on the JavaScript file, but I can't find any URL to the files.

Link: https://www.atrbpn.go.id/Peta-Bidang-Tanah

Specifically I want to get the "Zona Nilai Tanah" layer, but I think it's not a separated data from other layer.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using QGIS
use the **WFS service**
https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/online_resources/wfs.html

use the url

```
https://geosvc.atrbpn.go.id/geoserver/petabpn/ows?
```

[image]

[image]

**Seek permission of the data owner.**

The server is quite slow (even on a 1gb internet)

Answer (score 4):

Webmap layers cannot be exported out unless the provider gives the user some sort of export data tool within the map or if they provide a WFS url.  I would recommend contacting the map provider to see if they can provide the raw data via another means.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve all the layers by querying the GeoServer endpoint hidden behind the scene. If you also look at Network panel in your browser debugger, you will find all layers names.
By default (if it's intended or because not well protected, no idea in this case), you can export to shp within a zip file using the WFS endpoint from GeoServer (PS: be careful about legal implications as I do not know laws in your country, Indonesia)

Links below are not working anymore but the part about inspecting the application remains true.

<strike>To get the layers, you can copy and paste below URLs in the browser to download layers</strike>

<strike>* https://geosvc.atrbpn.go.id/geoserver/petabpn/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=petabpn:PENGUMUMANYURIDIS&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP</strike>
<strike>* https://geosvc.atrbpn.go.id/geoserver/petabpn/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=petabpn:ZONANILAITANAHNOLABEL&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP</strike>
<strike>* https://geosvc.atrbpn.go.id/geoserver/petabpn/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=petabpn:PersilBerdasarkanJenisHak&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP</strike>
<strike>* https://geosvc.atrbpn.go.id/geoserver/petabpn/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=petabpn:ZONANILAITANAHNOLABEL&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP</strike>